# Date condtion doesn't work on my application but work in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, request

I have a weird trouble with a request.
I have a table with a field 'datetime' named `'DATE'`.

Here an **exactly** exemple of one value : `2015-03-09 00:00:00.000`

I do in my application (in C#) a request like this : `'SELECT ... WHERE DATE BETWEEN datedeb AND datefin'`

Here an **exactly** exemple of the value of datedeb : `09/03/2015`

When i do the request in my application, it doesn't work at all, no results.

When i copy the request (via MessageBox.Show()) in SQL Server, it works.

When i change datedeb and datefin to 2015-03-09 in my application, it doesn't work.

When i change in SQL Server, it works.

I really don't know where is the problem ... have you some ideas ?

Comment: Can you add the c# code of your try?

Comment: Exception (including InnerException) + Stacktrace would not harm either

Comment: Are you sure 09/03/2015 corresponds to 2015-03-09 on the machine where the C# code is running? In a US locale 09/03/2015 would correspond to 2015-09-03.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger my request is build with a string builder, i'm sure at 99% that is this line : `req.Append(string.Concat("WHERE TE.DATE BETWEEN '", iDateDeb, "' AND '", iDateFin, "' "));`

Comment: @user469104 just a mistake when i type my message

Comment: Rather use parameterized commands... its easier to implement and kills SQL InjectionAttacks on sight =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from whatever where Date Between @begin and @end");
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("begin", yourbegin));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("end", yourEnd));
 ...
```

yourBegin and yourEnd are of type DateTime...

Comment: Oh ! I got an error using parameters : 
Failed to convert the date and / or time from a string

iDateDeb and iDateFin is from a datetimepicker. How can i use them in the good way ?

Comment: Lookup the functions DateTime.Parse and/or  DateTime.ParseExact... these allow to convert from string to DateTime

Comment: Alternative DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: You have to add a SqlConnection to the command too... but i'm pretty sure you know that (either in constructor or afterwards)

Comment: same problem .. damn it

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: yes i know for the connection , if i remove the where date between .. it works :/

Comment: No exception, just an empty table

Comment: No clue about your data, this is how it's done though

Comment: maybe you mixed up the format... exchanged 'dd' with 'MM' is a classic =)

Comment: try to parse the dates and put a breakpoint on the command and check the values of Day,Month,Year of the 2 dates

Comment: i have : 
`var iDateDeb = dateDeb.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var iDateFin = dateFin.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`
With the breakpoint dates still good, the problem is when i copy paste the EXACT request, same one, at 100%, in SQL Server, it works ... i don't understand

Comment: Neither do I, theres also a DateTime struct in Sql namespace... are you sure you connected to the same DB?

Comment: yep, because i do a request some lines before, i'm sure it's an issue with the date format but cannot find what

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN @begin and @end");
command.Parameters.Add("@begin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
command.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

I thinik, it is better if you can send the parameter as DateTime type so you don't have to deal with locale problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i'm a really stupid boy.
You know where was the problem ? I forgot to write the database i want to use in my ConnectionString. And i have several database who are very similar. 
My application was searching in an other table ... 
I'm very stupid !
Thank you a lot for your time, you're awesome, specially @Florian Schmidinger
Sorry for being stupid lol